# Querying a hash column in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, rails-activerecord

I have a hash column hash_column in my table table_1.

In table_1.rb

```
serialize :hash_column, Hash
```

The values stored in the column are

```
            hash_column
record1 => { index1 => '2'} 
record2 => { index2 => '3' } 
record3 => { index1 => '4'}
```

I want to get all records where hash_column's key is index1. 
The way I do it now is

```
 table_1.where("hash_column LIKE ?", "%index1%" )
```

This works fine. But is there a proper way to query a hash column using its key and value in Rails?

ps: I use mysql database

Comment: Hey! Check this [article](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-persist-hashes-in-rails-applications-with-postgresql/#awesomeness). Hope it helps!

Comment: if you are using Postgres there is Hstore which fits perfectly to store Hash data, we can query them easily like we do using activerecord.. http://www.schneems.com/post/19298469372/you-got-nosql-in-my-postgres-using-hstore-in-rails/

Comment: I want to achieve this using mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done with SQL. You cannot query your `Hash` because it is being serialized as `yaml` (or `json`) in a `text` column.. so basically your db does not know about the structure of the column because it's just text.

You can try using one of the JSON types for your column

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

and use `JSON_EXTRACT` or other function and use it in your `where clause`

more info
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html